# How to make such a button

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pamd1.png)

It needs to meet the following conditions

1. The button needs to have a slanted edge
2. Shadows on the bottom and right
3. Each corner has border-radius
4. The background color is gradient
5. The width of the button is dynamic

This is some data given by the designer

```
width: 128px;
height: 48px;
background: linear-gradient(317deg, #0099EE 0%, #0077EE 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #0482CC, 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(10, 127, 238, 0.3);
border-radius: 100px 4px 4px 100px;

width: 192px;
height: 48px;
background: linear-gradient(133deg, #FD7F5A 0%, #F53841 100%);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #C63A38, 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(255, 71, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 4px 100px 100px 4px;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use border-radius and clip-path together to cut of edges . grid can also help you to give an average ratio for each text portions .

here within a single button, what could be done :

```css
button {
  background:none;
  border:none;
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns:1.5fr 2fr;
  font-size:1.5em;
  filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 2px gray)
}
button span {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#0099EE,#0077EE);
  padding:1em 3em;
  color:white;
  border-radius:1.5em 7px 1.5em  1.5em / 1.5em 1em  0.5em  1.5em;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc( 100% - 1em) 100%, 0% 100%);
  box-shadow:inset 0 -2px 1px 2px #0681D3;
}
button span + span {
  margin-left:-0.75em;
  clip-path: polygon(1em 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
   border-radius:1.5em 1.5em 1.5em  7px / 0.5em 1.5em 1.5em  1em;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#FD7F5A, #F53841);
  box-shadow:inset 0 -2px 1px 2px #CD3C30
}
```

```html
<button><span>text 1</span><span> text 2 </span></button>
```

Comment: wow great !  I haven't used inline-grid , I'll study

Answer (score 0):

Use clip-path

```css
#buttonA {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 48px;
  background: linear-gradient(317deg, #0099ee 0%, #0077ee 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #0482cc, 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(10, 127, 238, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100px 4px 4px 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#buttonB {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 48px;
  background: linear-gradient(133deg, #fd7f5a 0%, #f53841 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #c63a38, 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(255, 71, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px 100px 100px 4px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="buttonA">buttonA</div>
  <div id="buttonB">buttonB</div>
</div>
```